# Why is the figure size (y-axis) fluctuating in this example?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, geopandas

I've got a map of the world on which I am iteratively plotting drought areas in a for-loop.

For reproducibility, data is here: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/global-droughts-events-1980-2001

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

from IPython.display import clear_output
sns.set_theme(style='whitegrid')

dr_geometry = gpd.read_file('data/dr_events.shp')
world_geometry = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

for y in dr_geometry.year.unique():
    clear_output(wait=True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 15))
    world_geometry.plot(ax=ax)
    dr_geometry[dr_geometry.year == y].plot(ax=ax, color='red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.1)
    plt.show();
```

This is working fine, except that the y-axis shrinks or expands on each iteration by a small but very noticeable amount, resulting in a choppy animation. How can I eliminate this behavior?

**Note:** Setting the `ylim` explicitly does not change this. Also I have tried moving the `subplots` instantiation outside of the for-loop, but this results in empty outputs.

An iteration output:

[image]

Comment: Hmm not sure. I downloaded the datasets and reproduced. A manual `set_ylim` doesn't work on my end either.

Comment: @tdy well thanks for taking a look. At the end of the day, it's not that terrible. Little inconsistencies like that bug me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ax.set_aspect('equal')` prevents the shifting on my end:

```py
for y in dr_geometry.year.unique():
    clear_output(wait=True)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(15, 15))
    world_geometry.plot(ax=ax)
    dr_geometry[dr_geometry.year == y].plot(ax=ax, color='red', edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.1)
    
    # set aspect ratio explicitly
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    
    plt.show();
```

---

Thanks to [@martinfleis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9978945/martinfleis) for pointing out the reason for the shifting:

- [geopandas#1121 - Consider scaling y-axis for unprojected map plots](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1121)
- [geopandas#1290 - ENH: scaling y-axis for plots in geographic CRS](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/1290)

> `.plot()` now automatically determines whether GeoSeries (or GeoDataFrame) is in geographic or projected CRS and calculates aspect for geographic using `1/cos(s_y * pi/180)` with `s_y` as the y coordinate of the mean of y-bounds of GeoSeries. This leads to better representation of the actual shapes than current hard-coded 'equal' aspect.

Comment: Unfortunately setting the `ylim` doesn't change anything even after giving it a buffer of 20 on either side: `set_ylim(-120, 120)`. Also, moving the instantiation outside of the for loop causes the whole thing to break completely.

Comment: @rocksNwaves see if `ax.set_aspect(1)` works on your end

Comment: See this issue for the explanation https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1121

Comment: @martinfleis I checked out the link, but I'm afraid I couldn't follow the conversation well enough to understand the relationship with my problem. Thanks for posting though.